# Registering multiple Tkinter listeners for an event

Tags: python, tkinter

Is it possible to register multiple listeners for an event?

Imagine a click on a `Treeview`. There might be a standard binding on the `<<TreeviewSelect>>`, e.g.

```
tree.bind('<<TreeviewSelect>>', some_function)
```

resulting in an `Entry` getting changed. But what if additional `Entry`s are added later, each to be filled with another part of the data in the `Treeview`?

As far as I know, there can be only one binding per event-type per widget, i.e. not multiple `<<TreeviewSelect>>` functions getting bound. The following

```
tree.bind('<<TreeviewSelect>>', function1)
tree.bind('<<TreeviewSelect>>', function2)
...
```

would result in the last function being the only one getting called. Is there a way to register multiple function calls?

Comment: So you want to run both function on the `<<TreeviewSelect>>` event?

Comment: Have you tried adding `add=True` to the `.bind()`?

Comment: Yes @DaniyalWarraich.

Answer (score 1):

To run both functions on that event, you could create `function3`:

```
def function3(event=None):
    function1(event)
    function2(event)
```

and then bind the `<<TreeviewSelect>>` event to `function3`.

```
tree.bind("<<TreeviewSelect>>", function3)
```

Edit: another way.
You could also add the `add=True` parameter, like this:

```
tree.bind("<<TreeviewSelect>>", function1)
tree.bind("<<TreeviewSelect>>", function2, add=True)
```

Comment: `function3` appears to be a "man in the middle", but I'd like to establish simple relationships between the `TreeView` and each widget that requires it.

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet demonstrates how to use `event_add` to any `widget` for multiple access to a selected function.

Once the event is created using the `<<name>>` tag it can be bound to a function using the `bind` method.

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

tree = ttk.Treeview(root)
tree.event_add("<<TreeViewSelect>>", "<Button-1>", "<Button-3>")

def me(event=None):
    print(event.widget)

tree.bind("<<TreeViewSelect>>", me)
```